# Solve the Initial-Value Problem $\quad x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+ u\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\,= u + 2x^2$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, cauchy-problem

Solve the initial value problem:
$$\,$$
$$ x\;\frac{\delta u}{\delta x}\,+\, u\;\frac{\delta u}{\delta y}\,=\, u + 2x^2,\qquad \mathrm{ with\;initial\, conditions}:\,u\,(x,\,\frac{1}{4}-x^2)=x$$

$$\,$$

This is what i've done so far, but I need help with this

1. Parameterize the initial conditions: $\quad x=x_0(s),\qquad y=\frac{1}{4}-s^2,\qquad u=u_0(s)$
2. Set of equations of characteristics: $\quad 1)\;\frac{dx}{d\tau}=x\qquad 2)\;\frac{dy}{d\tau}=u\qquad 3)\;\frac{du}{d\tau}=u+2x^2\qquad$

I don't know if this is even correct? $\;$Thank you

Comment: You should write  $\partial$ instead of $\delta$.

Comment: Thank you, this is my first time using the TeX commands. I thought delta was the partial derivative symbol for a minute.
Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: What you did is correct for me. Equivalently on Lagrange form : $$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{u}=\frac{du}{u+2x^2}=d\tau$$

Comment: I'm surprised, thank you. Now I have to combine/integrate these to arrive at a general solution??? If so, would this be the next step:
$$.$$
combining the first and second & first and third equations 
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{u}{x},\quad and \quad \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{u+2x^2}{x}=u+2x$$
and $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{u}{x}$ would be solved/integrated as follows??
$$u=c_1\,e^{\int\frac{1}{x}dx}\;=\;c_1\,e^{ln|x|}\,=\,c_1x \qquad therefore: \frac{u}{x}=c_1$$